# How to debug a Kivy application under ARC Welder

Tags: google-chrome, automatic-ref-counting, kivy

In order to debug my Python Kivy application under Windows, I've downloaded the ARC Welder tool and installed it under the Chrome browser under Windows. The installation worked fine, as well as as the loading of my .apk file, which was built under a Boot2Docker, Docker, Ubuntu using the Buildozer tool. The Chrome application displays the Kivy logo, then tells "loading" followed by a ":-("  icon.

How can i start a logfile to display the run-time error that causes the Kivy application crash?

Below the messages I found at the Chrome console display:

```
plugin not ready$
jscomp.scope.Plugin.postMessage @ plugin.js:336$
jscomp.scope.Plugin.onWindowStateChanged_ @ plugin.js:1579target.(anonymous function) @ 
extensions::SafeBuiltins:19EventImpl.dispatchToListener @ extensions::event_bindings:388target.(anonymous function) @ 
extensions::SafeBuiltins:19publicClassPrototype.(anonymous function) @ 
extensions::utils:151EventImpl.dispatch_ @ extensions::event_bindings:372EventImpl.dispatch @ 
extensions::event_bindings:394target.(anonymous function) @ 
extensions::SafeBuiltins:19publicClassPrototype.(anonymous function) @ 
extensions::utils:151dispatchEventIfExists @ extensions::app.window:335updateAppWindowProperties @ 
extensions::app.window:356
```

**Background Inspect:**

```
Delaying update install logic for 107 seconds
filesystem_background.js:253 ARC HTML5 FS: Request FileSystem: 35ms
main.js:354 ARC Window Popup: 97.5ms
main.js:388 ARC appWindow Init: 0.35ms
crash_reporter.js:298 prod: ARC
crash_reporter.js:298 arc_app_name: CFEduPlayer
crash_reporter.js:298 ptime: NaN
crash_reporter.js:298 crash_time: Wed Nov 02 2016 13:54:07 GMT-0200 (Horário brasileiro de verão)
crash_reporter.js:298 ver: 54.5021.629.0
crash_reporter.js:298 arc_build_tag: arc-runtime-54.5021.629.0
crash_reporter.js:298 message: plugin crash without minidump
crash_reporter.js:298 chrome_version: 54.0.2840.87
crash_reporter.js:298 app_id: cnlfghclafgbigiolhlbghjnenbaippl
crash_reporter.js:298 app_version: 0.1
crash_reporter.js:298 app_package_name: org.test.cfeduplay
crash_reporter.js:298 runtime_name: App Runtime for Chrome (Beta)
crash_reporter.js:298 runtime_update_url: https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx
crash_reporter.js:298 arch: x86-32
crash_reporter.js:298 nacl_arch: x86-64
crash_reporter.js:298 os: win
crash_reporter.js:298 target_arch: nacl_x86_64
crash_reporter.js:298 width: 960
crash_reporter.js:298 height: 632
crash_reporter.js:298 is_minimized: false
crash_reporter.js:298 is_maximized: false
crash_reporter.js:298 is_fullscreen: false
crash_reporter.js:298 runtime_updated_while_running: null
crash_reporter.js:298 sig: exit() called
crash_reporter.js:161 Crash reporting not enabled in Chrome.  Please enable it.
crash_reporter.js:318 FINISHED REPORTING CRASH
```

**Application Inspect:**

```
ARC JS Init: 222ms
plugin.js:654 Compositor is enabled
filesystem.js:97 File system is initialized.
plugin.js:336 Plugin not ready$jscomp.scope.Plugin.postMessage @ plugin.js:336
filesystem.js:227 ARC HTML5 FS: prefetchExtraFileMetadata_: 1.32e+03ms
plugin.js:800 3.661s + 0.078s = 3.740s (+0.0M virt, +0.0M res): App instance started

plugin.js:784 ARC Plugin Load: 3.45e+03ms
filesystem.js:286 Sending 147 file system cache entries to the plugin
plugin.js:800 3.661s + 0.080s = 3.742s (+0.0M virt, +0.0M res): Started renderer thread

plugin.js:800 3.661s + 1.634s = 5.296s (+0.0M virt, +0.0M res): Starting System

plugin.js:800 3.661s + 3.393s = 7.055s (+0.0M virt, +0.0M res): Android runtime initialized

plugin.js:800 3.661s + 3.453s = 7.115s (+0.0M virt, +0.0M res): Started SurfaceFlinger

plugin.js:800 3.661s + 3.668s = 7.330s (+0.0M virt, +0.0M res): Started native services

plugin.js:800 3.661s + 5.141s = 8.802s (+0.0M virt, +0.0M res): Package dexopted

plugin.js:800 3.661s + 6.548s = 10.209s (+0.0M virt, +0.0M res): System server started

gen_index.min.html:1 Is the 'geolocation' permission appropriate? See http://developer.chrome.com/apps/declare_permissions.html.
plugin.js:800 3.661s + 6.736s = 10.397s (+0.0M virt, +0.0M res): Activity onResume {org.test.cfeduplay/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity} (build 54.5021.629.0)

plugin.js:800 3.661s + 8.528s = 12.189s (+0.0M virt, +0.0M res): Exiting

gen_index.min.html:1 NativeClient: NaCl module crashed
plugin.js:978 plugin crashed$jscomp.scope.Plugin.showCrash_ @ plugin.js:978
```

regards,

Guidance about the debug procedure for Kivy on ARC Welder is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the last error screen with the ":-(" icon, right click the mouse and select "inspect" or "inspect background". I've isolated the root cause of the error, which was a missing prerequisite for adding the ffmpeg modules and CODECs to the buildozer environment. I've installed the ffmpeg package at the Ubuntu 14 system image and added it to the buildozer.spec requirements using the following statement:  requirements = kivy,ffmpeg. This fixed the issue and the .apk started to play the media, both under the ARC Welder browser platform, as well as under Android 6. Happy with the solution and ARC Welder is working perfectly!